# Integration laravel 7 log to slack

Tags: laravel, slack, laravel-7

I tried to integration error log laravel to slack notification. But when i tested to send log it can't send massage to slack. I followed this tutorial https://panjeh.medium.com/send-laravel-6-log-to-slack-notification-573a6d95a14e. And I've tested on route too

Here is it the `config.php`

```
'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['single','slack'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],

        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],

        'daily' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'days' => 14,
        ],

        'slack' => [
            'driver' => 'slack',
            'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
            'username' => 'Laravel Log',
            'emoji' => ':boom:',
            'level' => 'warning',
        ],
```

Here is it the route to test

```
Route::get('slack', function() {
    Log::error('Test');
    return 'Slack notif';
});
```

I've got the url too and have it put in `.env` `LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL=`

Comment: have you set  LOG_CHANNEL=slack

Comment: Now log channel is daily. Is it okay to change it to slack? Laravel log still run as usual, isnt it?

Comment: do you need both channels ?

Comment: also you  can Log::channel('slack')->inf("test"); specify channel

Comment: I need daily log and slack

Comment: try once  Log::channel(['daily','slack'])->info("test");

Comment: you can do this  'daily' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            'days' => 14,
   'channels' => ['daily', 'slack'],
        ], this is better i guess .so no need to specify channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change default log channels to slack.So you have to set

```
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
```

Also you can specify channels. Instead of changing channels

```
Log::channel('slack')->inf("test");
```

or you can do

```
Log::stack(['daily', 'slack'])->info("test");
```

or you can specify channels inside daily array.So that no need to change anythink

```
 'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily', 'slack'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ],
```

Comment: I got the answered. I changed `LOG_CHANNEL=stack` in `.env` and it works! Thanks for the clue!

Comment: @RayCoder.glad to here that you have solved your issue

Comment: I need daily and slack so the answered should be LOG_CHANNEL=stack not slack. Please edit it first